# SQL Statement Using Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, select, join

The database being used for this question is structured as follows with Primary Keys bolded, and Foreign Keys ' '.

---

Countries (Name, **Country_ID**, area_sqkm, population)

Teams (**team_id**, name, 'country_id', description, manager)

Stages (**stage_id**, took_place, start_loc, end_loc, distance, description)

Riders (**rider_id**, name, 'team_id', year_born, height_cms, weight_kgs, 'country_id', bmi)

Results ('**stage_id**', '**rider_id**', time_seconds)

---

I am stuck at the question of:

Q: Create a list (year, numridersborn) where we count the number of riders born in different years. Output columns: year, numridersborn. Order by: year

I am currently at :
`SELECT year_born AS "year", COUNT(rider_id) as "numridersborn" WHERE ....`

May I know how can I go about getting the solution?

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Are you getting an error or just the wrong output?

Comment: Please read online SQL tutorials and make an earnest attempt. You look to have some rep on SO, so should understand the rules. This feels like a [HW question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and we hate to overstep your learning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`year_born` is in the `rider` table already so there is no need to Join here.

Just:

```
SELECT year_born as year, count(*) as numridersborn  
FROM Riders 
GROUP BY year_born 
ORDER BY year_born;
```

Which is pretty much what you had already with the addition of the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: I see. Thank you @JNevill ! Appreciate it :)